# What is this nighttime creature?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

I almost stepped on this little critter. It blended into my garage floor. It is about about the size of my hand, with huge bulbous eyes that immediately caught my attention. There was a distinct white bump below\between the eyes.  It froze when I turned on the light and did not move at all until I turned the light off. Then it moved faster than my eyes could follow in the direction of my garden.

I am on an island in the San Francisco Bay, California. The current temperature is ranging from 50 (night) to 65 degrees and rainy season has just started (late this year). It blended so well with the garage floor that my camera had problems focusing on it.

[image]

Comment: Likely some type of gecko, they are active at night.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Any noise when startled (e.g. "barking")? Please also [edit] your post to include the location. Location can be an essential clue for identifications and should not be hidden in comments, which are ephemeral and often overlooked. ——— If possible clearer, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful since this could be one of several salamanders native to your area. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.californiaherps.com/lizards/images/pnocticolousmps03.jpg) perhaps? Found [here](http://www.californiaherps.com/lizards/pages/p.nocticolus.html) while searching for "gecko" in [California Lizards](http://www.californiaherps.com/lizards/lizards.html) It may not be an exact match due to geography, but perhaps it's a start. It at least sometimes has a white spot between the eyes, though not as pronounced as this one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an Arboreal Salamander (Aneides lugubris).
http://www.californiaherps.com/identification/bayareaherps.html#Lizards
http://www.californiaherps.com/salamanders/images/alugubrisbr1108.jpg